# Message id's in the main application loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I've written a simple *`Win32 App`* in *Visual Studio 2019* on *Win 10*. In the main message loop inside the `WinMain` function i have:

```
while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT) {

    if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);

        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("In the PeekMessage loop cnt: %d, msg: %d\n"), loop_cnt++, Msg.message);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
    }
...
}
```

I get following output:

```
In the PeekMessage loop cnt: 0, msg: 799
In the PeekMessage loop cnt: 1, msg: 49300
In the PeekMessage loop cnt: 2, msg: 96
In the PeekMessage loop cnt: 3, msg: 96
In the PeekMessage loop cnt: 4, msg: 275
In the PeekMessage loop cnt: 5, msg: 275
...
```

The odd is that the messages id's returned to the output like `799` or `49300` doesn't exist in the WinUser.h! So my question is what that messages are and where it comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

799 is [WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/wm-dwmncrenderingchanged).

49300 is a [registered message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew) (i.e. its value is in the range 0xC000-0xFFFF).

Comment: I knew about registered messages, so that was simple. For every other constant I don't immediately recognize I just go to [MagNumDB](https://www.magnumdb.com/) and take it from there.

Comment: `96` is an undocumented system message. But `275` is `WM_TIMER` (0x113).  It would help if you printed the message IDs in hex instead of decimal, as `winuser.h` (and other Win32 headers that define message IDs) use hex literals.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add a watch with message formatting (`Msg.message,wm`) in the debugger, and have the debugger help you out looking up the symbolic constants.